# Created database doesn't have compatibility level 130 in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2016-express

I installed SQL Server 2016 for individual user version. After that, I created a database but when I check the compatibility level of that database, it says 90.

When I was trying to change compatibility level of database it says

> Valid values of the compatibility level is 90, 100 or 120

But as I read the compatibility level of SQL Server 2016 is 130.

So, the problem is I need to create database that have a compatibility level is 130.

I have 2 instances of SQL Server in one system, SQL Server 2012 and newly installed SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Try `SELECT @@VERSION` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: It seems you're connected to the 2012 instance, since that's the last one that has compatibility level 90: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

Comment: It shows "MSSQL 2012 11.0.2100(x86)", But how it happen in mssql server 2016. i have sql server 2012 and 2016 both in one system that's way it shows like that

Comment: Yes i agree with you James. how can i change it

Comment: You'll need to install SQL Server 2016. It seems you've installed 2012 again. You can't simply "change" the instance version, so you'd be better off just starting again.

Comment: No i installed SQl Server 2016 and open it in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio

Comment: you must have connected to a SQL Server 2012 when create database. Verify , confirm before creating the database

Comment: You might just not be aware of the SQL Server instance name? If the first one was default from the installation, the second one is somewhat different. Try discovering your instances by going to Connect to Server -> expand the Server Name dropdown -> click Browse for more -> expand Database Engine. There you should see all the installed instances on your PC. Should be obvious which one is the new 2016 instance.